# ERROR 1115 when restoring stored procedure from MySQL dump file

Tags: mysql

At shell command prompt (backup and restore db):

```
mysqldump -u"username" -p"password" --host="127.0.0.1" --port=3306 --routines --triggers --no-data --add-locks my_db_schema > "C:\dumpfile.sql"
mysqladmin -u"username" -p"password" --host="127.0.0.1" --port=3306 --force DROP my_db_schema
mysqladmin -u"username" -p"password" --host="127.0.0.1" --port=3306 CREATE my_db_schema
mysql -u"username" -p"password" --host="127.0.0.1" --port=3306 --force my_db_schema < "C:\dumpfile.sql"
```

On the last command, I get an error:

> ERROR 1115 (42000) at line xxxx: Unknown character set: 'latin1BEGIN'

Line xxxx in C:\dumpfile.sql (first stored procedure in file):

```
delimiter varchar(255)) RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
```

**How can I fix that error?**

*I'm using Windows and MariaDB if that makes any difference*

---

If I add an extra carriage return between `latin1` and `BEGIN` the script runs fine.  That seems to be the only problematic line in the whole script.  Still looking for a solution to this issue.

Comment: *In the meantime I am going to programmatically add a carriage return before each `BEGIN` prior to running the script, but that seems like a terrible hack to me.*

Comment: I'm guessing the dump file is in unix text format (`\n` only), and you're importing it in Windoze, which expects `\r\n`.

Comment: Marc B: Thank you.  Actually, at the end of that one line, there was only a `\r`.  Not a `\r\n` or even a `\n`.  **Must be a bug for the Windows version.** *If you put your comment as an answer, I will check it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the dump file is in unix text format (`\n` only), and you're importing it in Windoze, which expects `\r\n`.

`\r`-only for a line ending is Mac-style, if I remember right.

Comment: +1: At the end of that one line, there was only a `\r`.  Not a `\r\n` or even a `\n`.  *Must be a bug for the Windows version.*

Comment: \r is the rather old (pre-OSX) Mac end-of-line. How did you produce that file?